# Git shows status clean, but checkout complains about overwriting untracked files

Tags: git, case-sensitive

Firstly:

```
git status
```

Result is clean.

Secondly

```
 git checkout fb/booking_interaction
 error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
 web/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/images/buttons/blockQuote.png
```

Thirdly, try to clear the untracked files. In the specified directory:

```
git clean -f .
```

Again, no changes and git checkout fails.

What is the problem?

Comment: Is your .gitignore ignoring PNG files? If you `mv blockQuote.png /tmp/` or stash it, does checkout succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to case sensitivity of the file system.

Looking at the problem. File listing:

```
> ls
imageButton.png
imagebutton.png
```

Check that git is set to case-sensitive

```
> vi .git/config
ignorecase = false
```

This machine is case sensitive. The machine the change was made on must have been too.

```
> git log
removeformat.png - renamed from removeFormat.png.
```

Since I have changed ignorecase, git status now shows the change.

```
> git status

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

blockQuote.png
bulletedList.png
```

Git clean also works as expected

```
git clean -f .
Removing blockQuote.png
Removing bulletedList.png
```

I can checkout the other branch without problems.

Comment: Running into the same issue and this did not solve it.

Comment: Did you confirm that there has been a case-change somewhere in the file name?